# How to make Phone app show favorites and contacts on app startup?

Tags: phone-app

When you open up the Phone app, it shows recent calls list (second tab) as the default tab instead of contacts list (third tab). This changed during the last upgrade.

How do I switch that back so by default it shows the favourites and contacts.

My stack:

- Samsung Galaxy J7,
- Android 8.1.0 Oreo,
- Samsung Experience 9.5.

I am using default, system Phone app.

Comment: This 100% relates to your phone version, system implementation etc. For example, on exactly the same Android version (i.e. Oreo), but on a different phone model (i.e. Motorola Moto Z2 Play, which uses stock, unmodified version of Android) this application [always displays favourites list](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209212/20449) instead of call history. Which, in my case, actually kills me, because I find favourites list incorrect and pointless and I am forced to always switch manually to call history tab.

Comment: I think my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209707/247431) should help you. Change "Call history" to Favorties or Contacts where needed. It was helpful for @trejder .